# Error when return a value from a function C++

Tags: c++, casting, return, return-type

I have this code in which I want to call the `char temp()` function from main function.
Also I want the return value of char temp() to be float as its a temperature value like :-
97.21, 98.33 etc

I used explicit as well as implicit typecasting to convert buf to float, but that also was throwing errors.
Can anyone please help ?

```
#define SERIALTERMINAL      "/dev/ttyUSB0"
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed)
{
    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

    tty.c_cflag |= CLOCAL | CREAD;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;         /* 8-bit characters */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     /* no parity bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;     /* only need 1 stop bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    /* no hardware flowcontrol */

    tty.c_lflag |= ICANON | ISIG;  /* canonical input */
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHOE | ECHONL | IEXTEN);

    tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNCR;  /* preserve carriage return */
    tty.c_iflag &= ~INPCK;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(INLCR | ICRNL | IUCLC | IMAXBEL);
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);   /* no SW flowcontrol */

    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    tty.c_cc[VEOL] = 0;
    tty.c_cc[VEOL2] = 0;
    tty.c_cc[VEOF] = 0x04;

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


char temp()
{
    char *portname = SERIALTERMINAL;
    int fd;
    int wlen;

    fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error opening %s: %s\n", portname, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    /*baudrate 115200, 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit */
    set_interface_attribs(fd, B115200);

    /* simple output */
    wlen = write(fd, "Hello!\n", 7);
    if (wlen != 7) {
        printf("Error from write: %d, %d\n", wlen, errno);
    }
    tcdrain(fd);    /* delay for output */

    unsigned char buf[83];
    /* simple canonical input */
    do {
        //unsigned char buf[83];
        unsigned char *p;
        int rdlen;

        rdlen = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
        if (rdlen > 0) {
            buf[rdlen] = 0;
            printf("%s", buf);
        } else if (rdlen < 0) {
            printf("Error from read: %d: %s\n", rdlen, strerror(errno));
        } else {  /* rdlen == 0 */
            printf("Nothing read. EOF?\n");
        }
        /* repeat read */
    } while (1);
return buf;
}

int main() {

unsigned char tem[83];
tem= temp();
printf ("%s", tem);

}
```

The error Im getting is -->

```
ser.cpp: In function ‘char temp()’:
ser.cpp:1:29: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 #define SERIALTERMINAL      "/dev/ttyUSB0"
                             ^
ser.cpp:53:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘SERIALTERMINAL’
     char *portname = SERIALTERMINAL;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ser.cpp:103:8: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
 return buf;
        ^~~
ser.cpp:72:19: warning: address of local variable ‘buf’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     unsigned char buf[83];
                   ^~~
ser.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ser.cpp:109:11: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char’ to ‘unsigned char [83]’
 tem= temp();
```

Comment: If you are writing in C, why use a C++ compiler?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Sir I dont know Ive been just trying to get this working since past 4 days, in the way learning somethings but been stuck at this since yesterday. Tried all combinations but it keeps getting messed up !! Please help if you can

Comment: 1) `char temp()` is declared to return a single character and you are returning an array. 2). It is a bad idea to return (a pointer to) a local array. 3) You cannot re-assign an array.

Comment: @jkb So I used char *temp and did all the relevant changes, but still Im getiing all sorts of errors. For instance this additional error ---> ser.cpp:60:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
         return -1;

Comment: you should return an array not a single char, also you are returning a pointer not the data inside of it

Comment: Since you are clearly writing C rather than C++ code, consider changing your function signature to `void temp(char *buf)` and calling it as `temp(tmp)`, which will allow you to get your string into `tmp` without returning an array and without memory allocation. Also, you should look at your `do...while` loop---it will never end.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what `temp` is supposed to do. Presumably read something, but what exactly? One line? One thing that looks like a floating point number? The entire stream?

Answer (score 1):

So I think you have a number of issues here.

The first error is easy to address. Simply replace `char *portname = SERIALTERMINAL;` with `char portname[] = SERIALTERMINAL;` and it should disappear.

The second error is due to the fact that you've defined `temp` as `char temp()` - meaning it returns a single `char` while `buf` is an array of `char`. Changing the definition of `temp` to be `char * temp` (notice the `*` in there) should fix that.

The third error is more problematic. Basically, the memory that `buf` uses is part of the function stack and it is "valid" only until the function ends. So when you return it, you are basically giving the caller a pointer to a memory that is no longer valid. In order to fix this, you'll have to dynamically allocate the memory (and then make sure it is released as well). In general it is a good idea not to hold array as part of the function stack as you do here, as they tend to be very vulnerable to overflow attacks.

Lastly, the last error should be changed by the fix to the second error. But notice that what you are doing here is copying the **pointer** that the function returns and not the **content** that the pointer points to. Easiest way to deal with that is to change the definition of `tmp` to be `char *tmp;` - than it will hold the pointer that `temp` returned.

Comment: Since `return buf;` is unreachable, it doesn't really matter if `buf` is a local buffer or not ;)

Comment: Yes and no. It's true that right now there's no exit condition from the loop before it, but it is important for two reason: 1. the code of the loop may change and expose the problem, 2. It's still a compiler error.